# How can I change a given JSON file (Python)?

Tags: python, json, parsing, maps

I'm new to Python and I'm currently building a python application (via Flask). I'm half way there, but I need to change a given JSON file to a different structure.

I have this JSON file given:

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
            "app_id": 27,
            "organization_id": "Organization_1"
        },
        {
            "app_id": 87,
            "organization_id": "Organization_2"
        },
        {
            "app_id": 88,
            "organization_id": "Organization_3"
        },
        {
            "app_id": 36,
            "organization_id": "Organization_1"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to bring it into a new structure like this:

```
{
    "organizations" : [
        {
            "organization_id": "Organization_!",
            "apps": [
                27,
                36
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "organization_id": "Organization_2",
            "apps": [
                87
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "organization_id": "Organization_3",
            "apps": [
                88
            ]
        } 
    ]
}
```

Do you have an idea how to create this output?
Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the first format is a mapping (similar a Python `dict`) from app_id to organization and you want to convert it to a mapping of organization to list of app_ids.  Given a list of apps where each element maps one app to one organizaiton, I would use that list to create a new map using a `dict`, i.e. if `apps` is the list from the first file:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: [])

apps = json.load(firstfile)['apps']
# d is mapping from organization_id to list of app_ids
for app in apps:
    org = app['organization_id']
    app_id = app['app_id']
    d[org].append(app_id)

# Create list of orgs from d
orgs = [{'organization_id': org, 'apps': apps} for org,apps in d.items()]

json.dump({'organizations': orgs}, secondfile)
```

Comment: Thank you, OldGeeksGuide!
I'll try that out. I have one last question: at `json.dump({...}, secondfile)` what is meant with **'secondfile'**?

Comment: Oh, ok, I know what you mean. Well, this JSON is not stored in a file, it is the output of a GET-request. But I could use a variable as an argument, instead of tha file 'firstfile' / 'secondfile', right?

Comment: Yes, I just used 'firstfile' and 'secondfile' as input and output, corresponding to the original post.  You can replace them with whatever input you have and whatever output you want.